C2 continuity with Bezier curves without sacrificing tangents?
I'd like to obtain acceleration continuity while being able to define the points a curve should go through, and the tangents at these points, keeping the computation simple enough to be performed as fast as possible.
Checking Wikipedia, I found this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_B%C3%A9zier_curve#Smoothly_joining_cubic_B%C3%A9ziers
However, the cited section mentions that in order to obtain C² continuity with two cubic Bézier curves $[P_0, P_1, P_2, P_3]$ and $[P_3, P_4, P_5, P_6]$, the constraints are that $P_4 = 2P_3 - P_2$ (that gives C¹ continuity on its own) and $P_5 = P_1 + 4(P_3-P_2)$. Given that $P_5$ is the control point that defines the tangent of the next point in the chain, that means totally losing control over the tangents at all points except the first two.
So, I wondered if it's possible to use higher-degree Bézier curves (quartic, ideally) so that by just constraining a point that is neither an endpoint nor its neighbor, so as to keep control over the passpoints and their tangents, we could obtain C² continuity.
Is it possible? If so, how? For example, if it's possible with quartic Bézier curves $[P_0, P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4]$ and $[P_4, P_5, P_6, P_7, P_8]$ with $P_5 = 2P_4-P_3$, how would $P_6$ (and possibly $P_2$ though I doubt it's constrained) need to be defined?

I think you need quintic (degree 5) curves to do this. These have 6 control points. So, at each end of the curve, you have 3  points that you can use to control tangency and curvature. Actually, controlling first and second derivatives is much easier than curvature, and roughly equivalent.
